# Migrating to Azure element default error

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm trying to migrate a SQL Server 2008 R2 database to SQL Azure, I'm using the deploy database to azure wizard and am getting the following error:

```
Error SQL71564: The element Default: [dbo].[SystemDateDefault] is not 
supported when used as part of a data package (.bacpac file)
```

I'm getting the same error code referencing a number default and a string default as well.  I've never tried this migration before and have no clue where to even start with this.

Anyone had this before or have any ideas what I should be doing?

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a bit of a dig around inside SQL and it turns out this is a default value for a user defined type.
I've removed it and things are going fine now.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I started by deleting Extended Properties (as my the error message stated, same SQL 71564 id). I used a script found here:

[Drop all extended properties on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368448/drop-all-extended-properties-on-sql-server)

But after many attempts I found it easier to script the entire db, make some adjustments, recreate the db from scripts and finally deploy to Azure.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify why you started by deleting those extended properties, why you found it easier to script the entire db, what those adjustments were, etc.

Comment: The same error ID applies to the question's case and to my case, which is slighty different: "Error SQL71564: The element **Extended Property**: [NAME_OF_PROP] is not supported when used as part of a data package". Second, the script didn't remove the ex.prop. Tird removing the prop. by hand was not an option because there are too many.